# Why Chrome can't inspect nodejs code in Docker container?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, docker, inspect

I try to start simple nodejs server inside Docker container and debug it with chrome://inspect or WebStorm. Debugging port 9229 is binded but inspection not works. On the other hand when I run same code without docker i can inspect it in chrome://inspect and in WebStorm both well.

Can anybody explain me why Chrome can't inspect nodejs code in Docker container???

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:8.2.1-alpine

WORKDIR /code

COPY package.json /code/package.json
RUN npm install && npm ls
RUN mv /code/node_modules /node_modules

COPY . /code

EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 9229

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

**alexey@home:~/app$ docker run -p 9229:9229 -p 8000:8000  node-dev**

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok 
npm info using npm@5.3.0  
npm info using node@v8.2.1  
npm info lifecycle @~prestart: @  
npm info lifecycle @~start: @

> @ start /code
> node --inspect app

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/5b225f7d-0e18-4ded-894b-a7993bb7da64 
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector 
HTTP server listening on port 8000
```

Comment: You need to make your debugger listen on `0.0.0.0`. It's currently listening on `127.0.0.1` which is only reachable from within the container (not your host).

Comment: @johnharris85 thank you for reply. it works now. I would like understand why wasn't work with 127.0.0.1. As I understand -p 9229:9229 bind internal docker's port with host's port which is reachable outside docker, isn't it?

Comment: 'Internal Docker's port' isn't really a concept. Docker creates an veth interface inside the container, and forwards traffic to that using a bridge from the host. If you do an `ifconfig` inside your container, you'll see multiple interfaces. Docker's will likely start with `172.xxxxx`. You _could_ bind to that (and it would work fine) but that's not practical as we don't know for the most part what it's going to be ahead of time, so binding on `0.0.0.0` solves the problem. `127.0.0.1` is the loopback for the _container_ only.

Comment: @johnharris85 very very thank you friend

Comment: @alexey2baranov please can you write your exact solution. I can not reproduce it. I understand: only a 0.0.0.0 binding of the debug port make access of chrome devtools possible. But how in detail?

Comment: @Gerd i did it very very long time ago. I rember 0.0.0.0 solved my problem only. That is all I can recollect today.

Comment: This is working for me but when the code is running its not hitting a debug point how can I hit the debug point?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

in your package.json `scripts`:

```
"debug": "nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 index.js",
```

in your docker-compose.yaml:

```
services:
  service_name:
    command: npm run debug
    ports:
      - 9229:9229
```

I am not 100% sure on this but I think that mapping the debugger to run on 0.0.0.0 exposes it to your local network meaning that anyone can connect to your machine IP on port 9229 will be able to debug your nodejs server. Beware your nodejs server has access to the filesystem. So do not run production (or development) servers with this ever.

Comment: This worked for me without the `EXPOSE 9229` in my Dockerfile.

Comment: @MitchellSimoens yeah you are right, that part is unnecessary. I will edit out my answer

Comment: On my case, it was still not working. To solve it, I had to add 127.0.0.1:9229 in the chrome://inspect -> Target discovery settings. For some obscure reason localhost:9229 was not enough. And just like @Gerd answer I also had to use a different port inside the docker.

Answer (score 5):

You need `node --inspect 0.0.0.0:8000` in container. Container port 8000 is mapped to host port 9229. So you must use localhost:9229 to connect chrome-dev-tools to node-debugger in container.

Details https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Comment: I used `node --inspect 0.0.0.0:9229` in the container.

Answer (score 5):

I had such issue while debugging jest tests. It was strange that the connection was not appearing in chrome://inspect when I was spinning tests with `--inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229` flag in the container, but I was able to connect to it by using Webstorm [Attach to Node.js/Chrome](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-node-js-remote-debug.html)﻿. Eventually, I got it worked by using Target discovery settings: [image]

Comment: Setting "127.0.0.1:9229" in target discovery settings was the missing link in addition to adding "--inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229". You are a savior.

Comment: Indeed, `localhost:9229` was not working, but `127.0.0.1:9229` was working. Maybe something to do with `localhost` pointing to a socket while `127.0.0.1` actually goes through the network?

Answer (score 0):

Instead, inside docker container, run app as:

> node --inspect=0.0.0.0 app.js

*with   **=0.0.0.0**   postfix