# Node js docker remote debugging chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, docker

I am running a node js server within Docker and I would like to be able to connect chrome dev tools on my host to node js on docker for debugging purpsoses.

This seems to be possible  as I followed the post here : [Why Chrome can't inspect nodejs code in Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855130/why-chrome-cant-inspect-nodejs-code-in-docker-container)

In fact by binding the ports 9229:9229 on the host and within docker to each other and in docker running the command when I start the node js

```
node --inspect-brk=[0.0.0.0] app
```

I am able to connect chrome dev tools to node js, however none of my break points work - I can only see the console logs within chrome.

How can I get my breakpoints to work? What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you get this working? It seems like a very answerable question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question I never got the above to work but I did manage to debug within a docker container using VS code.

There is another solution that I used here: https://keylocation.sg/our-tech/debugging-nodejs-in-docker-using-node-inspector

Looks like someone else found a solution here too: [Why Chrome can't inspect nodejs code in Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855130/why-chrome-cant-inspect-nodejs-code-in-docker-container?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I have this working with WSL2 on Windows with `docker compose`:

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:18

...etc

EXPOSE 9229 

ENTRYPOINT ["node"]
CMD ["service.js"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
...
  <service>:
    build:
      context: ./src/service
    ports:
      - 9229:9229
```

I run `docker compose up` then `docker compose stop <service>` to stop the service I'm debugging.

I then start the service again with debug options and port mapping:

```
docker compose run -p 9229:9229 <service> --inspect=0.0.0.0 service.js
```

I can then see the service in Chrome at chrome://inspect/#devices and select **inspect**.

[image]